# Expected value and quadratic sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider a sequence of random variables $(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} , \ L=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} v^k X_k$ with $\operatorname{E}(X_k)=0 \forall k$ I want to calculate: $$\operatorname{Var(L)}= \operatorname{E}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}v^k X_k \right)^2 - 0 \overset{!}{=} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} v^{2k} \operatorname{Var}(X_k)$$

How do I get to that result?

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\operatorname{Var}$ using `\operatorname{Var}`.

Comment: Thank you. I edited it

Comment: If i'm not mistaken the random variables should be independent ?

Comment: @MohammedM.Zerrak Yes:)

Comment: With the infinite series the equality does not hold in general.

Comment: Yes. But in this case we can assume that I can swap EV and series or Var and series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\operatorname{Var(L_{n})}= \operatorname{E}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}v^k X_k \right)^2{=} \sum_{k=0}^{n} v^{2k} \operatorname{Var}(X_k)$$

because $ v^k X_k$ are also independent :

If I'm allowed to assume that $$\operatorname{Var}(X_k)$$ and $$\operatorname{E}(X_k)$$ are bounded then you can take the limit as n approaches $\infty$

Comment: How do you get to $v^{2k}$?

Comment: Ok sorry I got it. Thank you very much:)